# A linux version of cygwin?

Tags: linux, cygwin, unix

I'm looking for a linux program that is simple and text-based, like cygwin, thats actually linux. I feel to much is missed out by cygwin like nano syntax highlighting and general linux programs. Is there any thing that runs with command prompt, like cygwin, that is a full text-based linux OS.

Comment: I think this belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: You can try running linux in a virtual machine, such as VirtualBox, and see how it works out for you.

Comment: I think Linux is a full text-based Linux OS.

Comment: I mean exclude gui linux

Comment: You can always press CTRL+ALT+F1 , CTRL+ALT+F2, ... and completely forget about GUIs.

Comment: You can install Linux without a desktop GUI, and use only the command prompt if you want to. This works great from within a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

if you want linux without any gui, simply don't install any gui.  the easiest way is to use any 'server oriented' distro, like Ubuntu Server, or CentOS.  If you want to do it on Windows, use a virtual machine, like VirtualBox, or try [coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/), which runs the linux kernel as a windows app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about nano syntax highlighting, but cygwin packages aren't very custom, there's a systems API abstraction layer (cygwin1.dll) that gives you Linux specific APIs. There are discrepancies in cygwin, for example vim by default runs with syntax off and nocompat unset... which sounds a lot like your issue. I've written some very low level programs under cygwin, using pthreads and such and never encountered breakage when compiling on Linux Linux. There are a lot of essentials missing in the default install of cygwin, so I'd suggest going through the package list and seeing what you need. Also don't forget the linuxutils package which includes such essentials as `more`.

Comment: As I remember in forums it has something to do with a different regEx and the commands werent reconized??